# Java subString/Accept first 3 characters in user input?

Tags: java, string, input

I am trying to make my program only accept the users input if the first 3 characters in their input/string, match the first 3 characters to an item of mine in my array.

This is what I have so far to check the input...

```
private static void checkInput(String[] items, String itemInput)
{
    boolean found = false;
    for (String item : items)
    {
        if (item.startsWith(itemInput.subString(0, 3)))
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR. You must enter a valid item. (Exiting Program)");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

It appears to be complaining on the subString part. "if(item.startsWith(itemInput.subString(0,3){"

symbol: method subString(int, int)
location: variable itemInput of type String.

How can I fix this? So the user can input simply 3 of the first letters of an item stored in my array, and it pass through as true and proceeds on with the program?

Comment: It is `substring` with a lowercase s.

Answer (score 0):

The method `substring` is all lower case (not subString).
See for references http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that substring should be all lower case. This is simply the only problem I can find.